# Unable to start MongoDB - IndexCatalog has left over indexes

Tags: mongodb

I had copied a collection from prod to QA env. and restored it using Indexing option ON in my QA env.

However, my `mongodb` server(primary) stopped working.

We did `reindexing` but it still doesn't start.

However, our secondary node is still up.

I can see below  logs:

```
2019-01-14T03:48:22.418+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Expected index data is missing, rebuilding. NS: analytics.activities_prod Index: payload.pageId_1_payload.topicId_1_payload.lessonId_1_cid_1 Ident: index-32--384934585478986536
2019-01-14T03:48:22.419+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten] found 5 index(es) that wasn't finished before shutdown
2019-01-14T03:48:22.419+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal assertion 40592 InternalError: IndexCatalog has left over indexes that must be cleared ns: analytics.activities_prod at src/mongo/db/db.cpp 464
2019-01-14T03:48:22.419+0000 F -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after fassert() failure

2019-01-14T03:48:22.426+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
```

Comment: 1) How did you copy the files? Using the filesystem `cp` command? or `mongodump` and `mongorestore` ?  2) are you seeing this `fassert` on the source prod environment, or the target/QA environment?

Comment: 1. I copied using mongodump and mongorestore.
2. I can see this error on target/QA environment.

Comment: 1. I copied using mongodump and mongorestore.
1a.. I found this in log file after mongorestore 
estoring indexes for collection analyitcs1
.activities_prod from metadata
2019-01-11T13:08:17.332+0000    Failed: analyitcs1.activities_prod: error creating indexes for analyitcs1
.activities_prod: createIndex error: EOF
2. I can see this error on target/QA environment.

Comment: Are you running the latest versions of the binaries?

Comment: Thanks Nic. I'm using 3.6.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction for errors like this would be to upgrade to the latest release of your major version. In your case that would be 3.6.9 or even upgrade to the latest 4.0.x release.

Comment: Thanks Nic. Will do that and let you know.

Comment: We have upgraded to 3.6.9. But facing the same issue.
The Db version is upgraded in file.
2019-01-15T14:34:49.134+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.9

Comment: DO you think I need to again run the repair.